# Send follow-up mail based on the links clicked on an email in journey builder in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have an journey where entry source is a data extension. In this journey I used an email activity to send an email. Inside that email I have different links. now if a subscriber clicks a link that sent to them then I have to send a particular follow up email for that. if subscriber clicks different link then I will send another follow up mail for that. how can I achieve this by using journey builder in marketing cloud.

Comment: You would want to take a look at [Engagement Split](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_use_the_engagement_split_activity.htm&type=5) in Journey Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it with multiple Engagement Split Activity.
I have attached a sample journey with initial email with 2 CTA links (1: URL to google website and 2: URL to Salesforce website). In the first engagement split, I selected only those audiences clicked the Google CTA link and attached the second engagement split in the "No" branch from first engagement split. This works perfectly.

[image]

[image: Link 1]

[image: Link 2]

Comment: Thank you Kelvid for this answer but if someone have more than 10 or 20 links then we have to repeat the engagement split step. So that why it becomes more lengthy. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: If you have many links to tracks, IMHO, I would use SQL activity in automation studio to track the clicks of each link and insert into DE, then create a attribute group. After that you can use the decision split in journey builder to split into multiple branches.

Comment: Thank you @Kelvid I have followed the steps mentioned by you. I used SQL activity in automation studio to track the clicks of each link and inserted them  into a DE. Then I created an attribute group but I am not able to link that DE that I created with the attribute group . Can you help me out?.

Comment: Yes, you are not able to link to that specify DE, but you link the DE that has the email tracking that you want to the "Contact" in Data Designer. Post that, in journey builder, you have to select the Attribute group you created for the decision split.